# recvfrom() doesn't receive complete buffer

Tags: c, sockets, udp

In a client-server architecture based setup, my client sends data over UDP socket which is of size 116 bytes. But on the server side, the program receives only 24 bytes. Any help is appreciated.

I tried capturing the packet using wireshark. But the packet looks to be intact. But on the server(receiving) side buffer data is lost. I suspect somrthing is wrong with my recvfrom()

```
//Client sends data
uint32_t final_cmd[DISC_REQ_SIZE] = {0};
..
..
n = sendto(sockfd, (const char *) final_cmd, sizeof(final_cmd), 0,
            (struct sockaddr *) &serveraddr, ser_len);


//Server receives data
uint32_t buffer[BUFSIZE];
..
..
while(1)
{
    bzero(buffer, BUFSIZE);
    n = recvfrom(sockfd, buffer, BUFSIZE, 
            0, ( struct sockaddr *) &cliaddr, 
            &len); 
..
..
```

Expected result : Sever receives complete 116 B of data
Actual result : Server receives only 24 B of data

Comment: Post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  From what you've posted, you'll only get guesses.  You haven't even established that you really are receiving just 24 bytes of data and not the entire 116 bytes.  For that matter, you haven't even established from the posted code that you're sending 116-byte packets.

Answer (score 1):

The third parameter of `recvfrom` (length) wants the length of the buffer in bytes but you are passing the number of elements.

Try changing

```
n = recvfrom(sockfd, buffer, BUFSIZE, ...
```

to

```
n = recvfrom(sockfd, buffer, sizeof buffer, ...
```

Also, on modern systems do not use `bzero` (is deprecated), instead:

```
memset(buffer, 0, sizeof buffer);
```

Comment: Thanks David. I made both the changes. But still issue is observed

Comment: @AthulSukumaran then you are doing something else wrong that we can't see.  Please edit your question to provide a [mcve], including the actual definitions of `DISC_REQ_SIZE` and `BUFSIZE`.

Comment: @David there is no need to use `memset()`/`bzero()` at all, if you simply don't exceed the length that `recvfrom()` returns when using the `buffer` after reading it.